# Spring cloud stream with RabbitMQ binder throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: Message body is too large

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm using spring cloud stream 4.0.4 with rabbitmq binder 4.0.4 to proccess messages in spring boot 3.1.3 app. I'm also using rabbitMQ 3.10.0. The thing is, there is an bug in my application when the message size is 94MB i will get an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Message body is too large (94664210), maximum configured size is 67108864. See ConnectionFactory#setMaxInboundMessageBodySize if you need to increase the limit.
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.CommandAssembler.consumeHeaderFrame(CommandAssembler.java:109) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar!/:5.17.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.CommandAssembler.handleFrame(CommandAssembler.java:172) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar!/:5.17.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQCommand.handleFrame(AMQCommand.java:105) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar!/:5.17.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:115) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar!/:5.17.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:746) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar!/:5.17.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar!/:5.17.1]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:673) ~[amqp-client-5.17.1.jar!/:5.17.1]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

My application.properties:

```
spring.cloud.function.definition=result
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.result-in-0.group=coreGroup
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.result-in-0.destination=result
```

The Bean (it is calling simple auditRepository.save(auditRecord)):

```
    @Bean
    public Consumer<ResultMessage> result() {
            return auditController::storeAuditRecord;
    }
```

I tried to set DLX with DLQ in application.properties like this:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.result-in-0.consumer.max-attempts=2
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.result-in-0.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.result-in-0.consumer.dead-letter-exchange=resultDLX
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.result-in-0.consumer.error-channel-enabled=true
```

I have also tried to set max size:

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.result-in-0.consumer.max-message-size=209715200
```

but it will always crash. Message is not pushed to DLQ and setting max size did not do anything.

It is not mandatory for me to process that big messages, I can somehow check the size in code, but sometimes there is important payload which can be up to 100MB (happens 1 in 1.000 cases).

After the exception is thrown, the consumer is not able to work and the app will stop working for users as they can't get the result payload after saving audit record.

How can I push this message to DLQ to future investigation?

Answer (score 4):

This is due to a recent change to the amqp-client to prevent OOMs with very large messages; the error is detected before Spring receives the message; hence there is no way for Spring to send it to a DLQ.

```java
/**
 * Maximum body size of inbound (received) messages in bytes.
 *
 * <p>Default value is 67,108,864 (64 MiB).
 *
 * @param maxInboundMessageBodySize the maximum size of inbound messages
 */
public void setMaxInboundMessageBodySize(int maxInboundMessageBodySize) {
```

You can increase the allowed size by adding a customizer bean to your application. e.g. to increase it to 128MiB:

```java
@Bean
ConnectionFactoryCustomizer cust() {
    return cf -> cf.setMaxInboundMessageBodySize(1024 * 1024 * 128);
}
```

Comment: There are side effects of this behaviour. Concurrent consumed messages are duplicated. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues

Comment: Spring has no control over this, the amqp-client closes the connection when a message that is too large is received; this means that any other in-flight message(s) will also be requeued. RabbitMQ makes no promise of "exactly once delivery" semantics, only "at least once"; there are many scenarios (such as this one, or any network glitch etc., etc.) that can cause duplicate deliveries; it is up to the application to detect duplicates and/or make updates idempotent. You can mitigate it by using `CacheMode.CONNECTION` so each listener gets its own. But you still need to handle dups.

Comment: Thank you very much for this Information :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution mentioned by Gary works and explains the logic behind. As I was searching for answers I have also found that Spring version 3.2 brings settings to change max inbound size.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.2.0-RC1-Release-Notes#limited-message-body-size-with-rabbitmq

In application.properties, you can set the size as:

```
spring.rabbitmq.max-inbound-message-body-size=XY
```

But... there is still problem with messages that are bigger as I can not catch the exception. So My solution is to calculate size of payload in spring function (as producer) every time I want to send the message to RabbitMQ:

```
    long byteSize = calculateObjectSize(resultMessage);
                            System.out.println(byteSize);
                            // Check if the byte size exceeds the allowed limit (50MB)
                            if (byteSize > 50 * 1024 * 1024) {
                                // Handle the case where the payload exceeds the limit
                                // You can return an error message or throw an exception here.
                          return error;
                            }

    public long calculateObjectSize(ResultMessage object) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream objectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(byteStream);
            objectStream.writeObject(object);
            objectStream.flush();
            return byteStream.size();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1; // Handle the error as needed
        }
        }
```